# How to pass 2 variables in viewVars

Tags: cakephp, cakeemail

```html
       $message[0]  = $unique_password[0]['users']['firstname'];
  
  $message[1]='Please click on this link to reset your password: http://test.com/reset_password?password='.$unique_password;


  $Email = new CakeEmail();
  $Email->config('smtp');
  ***$Email->viewVars($message[0],$message[1]);***
  $Email->template('forgetpassword')
  ->emailFormat('html')
  ->to($email)
  ->from('app@domain.com')
  ->subject('Password: Urbanbeauty Network')
  ->send();
```

i need to send two variables on my view $message[0] & $message[1] in viewVars. How do achieve this? Please help.

Answer (score 0):

You only need to do this, $this->set('message', $message); and then in you view will you have $message[0] and [1]

Comment: David,it says set is undefined function. Thanks David i got it now.like this $Email->viewVars(array('message' => $message));